# Properly return org.w3c.dom.Document as JSON using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I have a function which returns type org.w3c.dom.Document, and my Jersey resource lets it return either as XML or JSON. It returns the XML fine, however, for JSON,  it returns a simple string, which is just the XML using Application/JSON. How can I make it encode to JSON properly?

I'm open to changing the return type of the function to something that can properly be serialized by Jersey

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own [MessageBodyWriter](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for application/json media type and org.w3c.dom.Document class.